# Подскажите пример проекта на ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите OpenSource проекты или готовый пример на ASP.NET MVC 5, которые можно рассматривать как образец структуры проекта и стиля кода.

Comment: а разве образец структуры MVC не создаётся из коробки при создании проекта?

Comment: @MasterAlex, мне хотелось бы не просто структуру, а образец готово сайта, возможно даже который эксплуатируется. Так гораздо приятнее знакомится с технологией, когда перед тобой есть реальный проект.

Comment: Держи, ссылку на решение, в решение присутствует разные проекты, в том числе CinemaWeb - проект на ASP.NET MVC.
https://yadi.sk/d/UA_3QalDsegocQ